# Graph Theory - Algorithm for Number of Walks Between 2 Vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

I'm looking for an algorithm to be implemented in C++ that when given the adjacency matrix of a directed and unweighted graph, will calculate them number of walks between 2 given nodes.

I tried Googling for one, but didn't have any luck. I understand that the solution will likely be O(n^2) complexity.

Thank you.

Comment: In all likelihood there are either 0 or an infinite number of paths. Maybe you want to place some restriction on the possible paths?

Comment: Also have a look at http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1084515 It's O(n^6) though

Comment: I wonder if paths is intended instead of walks. Number of paths between two points could probably be calculated in O(N^2).

Comment: The number of walks of length k is e_s' A^k e_t, where A is the adjacency matrix of the graph and e_v is the column vector with a 1 in the position corresponding to vertex v and 0s elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `O(E)` algorithm that works in case the graph is acyclic.

Start with the source node labeled `1` and all other nodes labeled `0`. Then, in BFS order from the source node, label each node as sum of the labels in all its parent nodes. The final label in the destination node is your answer.